# why aren't my UITableViewDataSource functions getting called?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

As I run the code I am successfully feeding JSON data into my application at the rendering of this associated UIView.  I have a tableView adequately linked to this file, when I run the application I see the tableview itself. BUT none of the 3 datasource functions are automatically getting called - the 'wtf' print statement, after 2 hours of playing with this, will.not.print.

am I missing something?  This code is *identical* to all other tableviewdatasource code I've written and this simply won't work or render the JSON data I am supplying it with

does anyone have thoughts or suggestions?  Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ChooseUserViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


var users: [BackendlessUser] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadUsers()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: UITableViewDataSource

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("wtf")
    return users.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("chooseCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    print("wtf!")

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.email

    return cell


}
}
```

Comment: Have you asigned your TableView inside Storyboard to your ViewController as Delegate & Datasource?

Comment: Have you set the datasource ?

Comment: @derdida It's the other way round. :P

Comment: HAAAAA you are the best - of course I rebuilt the storyboard view and left this out - thank you so much!

Comment: show the code of `loadUsers` method

Comment: @ZeMoon i hope he knows what i mean ;) - and seems it is working now :)

Comment: I've never been so excited to see "wft!" print on my console repeatedly....

Answer (score 0):

You have tableview with datasource and delegate connected with view controller in storyboard(Interface Builder).

Answer (score -1):

In case you're forgotten to set the `dataSource` and `delegate` in your Storyboard using `Ctrl+Drag` you need to specify in your `viewDidLoad` that you're the `dataSource` and `delegate` like in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  tableView.delegate = self
  tableView.dataSource = self

  loadUsers()
}
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

The Answer: I had not connected the delegate and the datasource of my table object to the view controller - OOPS! I feel silly but that was clearly my issue